# Clean way of turning nullable types into reference

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, nullable

I am trying to generalise a solution I've written so that it can be applied across similar problems.

I have a number of different objects which all contain nullable doubles. I want to somehow pass them (the doubles) in a dictionary which will then put in the data directly into the object in question.

This would work pretty simply if the doubles were reference types, but they're not.

So I need a solution for referring to them by reference. The only thing I could think of is creating my own Class which contains a double, but that's a lot of work since I use a lot of Double's code - and far as I know you can't extend value types.

Any ideas on how I can go about it?

Added - Here's an example code sample of the sort of thing I'm trying to do. It's not the actual code.

```
void ReadTable(Dictionary<string,double?> dict)
{
//read some sort of table here by usign the string as the headers
dict["header"] = Convert.toDouble(tableValue);
//etc...
}

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
//fill it up from the table
Dictionary<string,double?> req = new Dictionary<string,double?>();
req.add("header",myObject.something);
req.add("header2",myObject.somethingElse);
ReadTable(req);

MyOtherObject myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject();
//fill it up from the table
Dictionary<string,double?> req2 = new Dictionary<string,double?>();
req2.add("aheader",myOtherObject.m2something);
req2.add("aheader2",myOtherObject.m2somethingElse);
ReadTable(req2);
```

Comment: Could you explain your issue a little bit more? What exactly are you trying to do? Could you give a code sample (even if it won't work) please?

Comment: I wrote some example code to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to have (non-compiling code, for illustration only):

```
Dictionary<string, ref double?> lookup = ...

double? someField = ...

lookup.Add("foo", ref someField);
```

and then later:

```
lookup["foo"] = 123.45;
```

and have *that* appear for code that knew about `someField`: then indeed, that can't and won't work. Well, there's some insanely hacky ways, but *don't do that*. What you describe is indeed the right way to do it:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    public double? Value {get;set;}
}

Dictionary<string, MyWrapper> lookup = ...

MyWrapper someField = new MyWrapper();

lookup.Add("foo", someField);
```

and then later:

```
lookup["foo"].Value = 123.45;
```

Then any code referencing `someField.Value` will see the new value.

You can perhaps generalize this with generics.

If you want to minimize code changes, you could perhaps add an operator:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    public double? Value {get;set;}
    public static implicit operator double?(MyWrapper value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.Value;
    }
}
```

which will at least work for any code that does things like:

```
double? tmp = someField;
```

or:

```
SomeMethodThatTakesNullableDouble(someField);
```

Comment: Yes you understood the problem correctly (I added some example code).

The problem is that I need to use Double.Parse() and other functions - and what will reference my object expects "double?". So I'd need to stay converting them three times. Which isn't very clean.

Comment: Just looked up the implicit keyword. That might work without many changes - I'll just change the objects to use this wrapper. Hopefully there isn't any code which calls 'getType'...

Comment: Ok, it won't work because they need to go into the database and I'm pretty sure the mysql parameter adding-function will check the type. And I can't override getType...